# Illegal modifier for the variable print; only final is permitted on javaCC

Tags: java

[This is the error I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7k9A.png)
So i'm working on java CC, but I keep getting this error from creating arraylists and strings variables on the .jj

```
public class Parser
{
  public static void main(String args []) throws ParseException
  {
    Parser parser = new Parser(System.in);
    while (true)
    {
      System.out.println("Reading from standard input...");
      System.out.print("Enter a TREE:");
      private static ArrayList nodosCheck = new ArrayList();
      private static ArrayList nodos = new ArrayList();
      private static String raiz;
      private static String print="Todo anda bien";
      System.out.println("Bienvenidos");
```

someone know what is wrong?
I cant run the application since the error is from the .java file of the parser.
but idk how to solve this on the .jj file
This are lists and variables that I have to modify during the program, just to clarify.

Comment: `private static String raiz;` is how you declare fields.  Fields are declared at h\the class level not as a local variable

Comment: What do you think `private` and `static` mean in this context? More to the point, what would a *non-private*, *non-static* local variable look like, and how would it be different?

Comment: Access modifiers like `private` and the keyword `static` can be used only at the class level. That means they cannot be used inside a method, constructor, or any other block that is encapsulated by a class.

Comment: Please don't post errors as images